# Can injecting a field member with Dagger be done with only a constructor

Tags: android, dagger-2

I inject a field member as follows:

```
@Inject
lateinit var repository: Repository
```

What I have noticed is that repository will only get set if I use a component builder:

```
init {
    DaggerLoginViewModelComponent
        .builder()
        .build()
        .inject(this)
}
```

But I have read in several places that the field member will get set even if you just mark the constructor of the class you want instantiated with Inject:

```
class Repository @Inject constructor() {

}
```

But I have not found this to be true. Even with the constructor having the Inject annotation present, I still need to run the builder. Can someone confirm whether this is true or not.

Comment: The component should be build... or the activity or fragment should extend `DaggerActvity`/`DaggerFragment` **in order to let know dagger which class wants to gets its field injected.** / to create a dependency graph

Comment: @SantanuSur Theoretically Dagger should know what class gets injected - the object type is specified. In my example Dagger should know that it must inject a Repository. You shouldn't have to build a component to tell Dagger that.

Comment: Please include a _minimal, full, working_ example in your question that produces the `null` field. You don't show the component or where/how it gets used. Your snippets don't suggest any errors or problems out of context like this. Marking the constructor is enough to let Dagger handle the object creation and inject fields, so your example should work.

Answer (score 0):

The way field injections work is through a supplemental method on the Dagger component, in this case `inject(this)`.

If you look at the Dagger generated code, you'll see that `inject()` method's body contains the code to perform the member injection.

Here's how the generated code would look-

```
@Override
public void inject(Foo instance) {
  injectFoo(instance);
}

private injectFoo(Foo instance) {
  Foo_MembersInjector.injectRepository(instance, repositoryProvider.get());
  return instance;
}

...

public final class Foo_MembersInjector implements MemberInjector<Foo> {
  public static void injectRepository(Foo instance, Repository repository) {
    instance.repository = repository // <-- this is where the actual injection happens
  }
}
```

You're right when you say that Dagger knows how to construct the Repository object, but it doesn't know that this object has to be injected in a separate class. And that only happens when you call the `inject()` method with the instance of specific type, which is how it generates code to perform the injection.

Hope this helps.